# Lightnig Web Component Wire

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, web, wire

Hi I have set up a wire service which returns the data from the Apex side  , in the Apex I have ABC__c  as a field , how can i access the field in JS of LWC.

Below is my code:

```
@wire(ASD, { CFG: '$CFG' }) TCG({ error, data }) {

        }
         if(data.fields.ABC__c === "PPPP") {
          this.TCD = true;
        }
```

currently i am getting error as fields is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Try below method and here `ABC__c` is your field name which you used in apex.
Below is the code for your reference

```
@wire(ASD, { CFG: '$CFG' }) 
     TCG({ error, data })
     {
        if (data) {
            this.field= data.ABC__c;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;

        }
    }
```

Let me know if you have any other problem

Comment: Value is coming as undefined

Comment: can you show me your apex?? and the value you is sending right or not ?

Comment: @Tiina You're returning an array `data[...]`, so `data[0].ABC__c` would be correct here.